# Angular translation not working with angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have an **Angular9** app. Apart from the **app.module.ts** there is one more module, **custom.module.ts**.  Here is the

**package.json**

```
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
"@angular/common": "9.1.11",
"@angular/compiler": "9.1.11",
"@angular/core": "9.1.11",
```

For translation

**1)** I have added `@ngx-translate/core` and `@ngx-translate/http-loader`

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",
```

**2)** then in **app.module.ts** under `imports`

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
           provide: TranslateLoader,
           useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
           deps: [HttpClient]
      }
}),
```

and

```
// required for AOT compilation
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): any {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/");
}
```

Same i did for my **custom.module.ts**.

**3)** app.component.ts

```
// Add languages
this.translateService.addLangs(["en", "nb", "sv"]);

// Use a language
this.translateService.setDefaultLang("en");
this.translateService.use("en");
```

**4)** files in **assets/i18n/en.json**

```
{
    "noSelectMessage": "Select to see detail."
}
```

and now where i use traslate pipe in a component of **custom.moule.ts**

```
<span>{{'noSelectMessage' | translate}}</span>
```

it shows same **noSelectMessage**

and If i check source tab in browser there is no **i18n** folder under assets.

What can be the issue?

Comment: can't see an issue on first look. Can you please provide a https://stackblitz.com/ example.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a173ro here you have an working example.

Comment: @SehaxX still not working, do i need include it in custom module as well , translate module under imports as well as for app.module?

Comment: it also will not translate on load, solution seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907829/translate-service-not-working-on-load-page

Comment: In my case I have an snake case converter interceptor, that was changing all the keys. Make sure no interceptors are messing up with your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the translation service in a component of **custom.module.ts** and in **custom.module.ts** file I was doing

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
           provide: TranslateLoader,
           useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
           deps: [HttpClient]
      }
}),
```

all I need to do is to just import `TranslateModule`, to support translate pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If there's any specific component that is not picking the values, check if your component is added in the declarations array of your module.